# Hardhat external dependencies (sol files)

Tags: npm, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I have a smart contract with the following import statements:

```
import "@prb/contracts/PRBMathSD59x18.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

How to I get Hard Hat to download these external contracts and import them when compiling?

I have tried changing the first line to:

```
import "@prb/math/contracts/PRBMathSD59x18.sol";
```

As suggested by this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114376/how-to-compile-external-contracts-using-hardhat) but without any success. It might be because I'm using [scaffold-eth](https://github.com/stevenpslade/scaffold-eth-tailwind) which recommends using `$ yarn deploy` to build the contracts.

I tried installing them manually.

```
$ npm install @paulrberg/prb-math@2.5.0
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@paulrberg%2fprb-math - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@paulrberg/prb-math@2.5.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/developer/.npm/_logs/2022-10-09T22_29_12_712Z-debug-0.log
```

I haven't managed to find how to do this in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in time im writing this the last version of `prb`is `2.4.3` and not `2.5.0` so this is your problem .The version you try to install no exist .

So you have 3 dependencies so you need to install it , I recommend to execute this commands :

- [prb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prb-math) : `npm install prb-math`
- [openzepellin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openzeppelin/contracts) : `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts`
- [chainlink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chainlink/contracts) : `npm install @chainlink/contracts`

After installing, if your contract is correct, you will be able to compile